# Can the instantaneous frequency be always derived from an analytic signal?

Tags: frequency, phase, hilbert-transform

Instantaneous frequency can be defined as a derivative of an instantaneous phase of an analytic signal which can be nicely seen in practice in [this example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) from Scipy's documentation. But it seems like it does not always work like this. I played with the code from the example and obtained varied results like for this sine wave with frequency gradually changing from 2 to 12Hz:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import hilbert, chirp

duration = 1.0
fs = 400.0
samples = int(fs*duration)
t = np.arange(samples) / fs
w = 2*np.pi*(2 + 10*t)
signal = np.sin(w*t)
analytic_signal = hilbert(signal)
amplitude_envelope = np.abs(analytic_signal)
instantaneous_phase = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
instantaneous_frequency = (np.diff(instantaneous_phase) /
                           (2.0*np.pi) * fs)
```

This is the resulting figure with the original frequency plotted in grey on the bottom subplot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax0.plot(t, signal, label='signal')
ax0.plot(t, amplitude_envelope, label='envelope')
ax0.set_xlabel("time in seconds")
ax0.legend()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.plot(t, 0.5*w/np.pi, lw=2, color='gray')
ax1.plot(t[1:], instantaneous_frequency)
ax1.set_xlabel("time in seconds")
fig.show()
```

[image]

In the bottom plot the blue line and the grey line go in the same direction, but there is a huge discrepancy between the two and I do not mean the ever-present edge effect. The calculated instantaneous frequency is rising at the rate that is almost a double of the actual reaching values above 20Hz at the end.

I tried it for other sine waves with constant amplitudes and varied frequencies getting similar results. Only when I used a signal with a constant frequency the blue line was matching the grey line on the bottom plot. My question here is: are there any conditions a signal must meet for the definition of the instantaneous frequency to hold true, so it can be derived from the instantaneous phase of the analytic signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the phase term is changing with time at the rate of $t^2$ for the frequency ramp, and since the instantanous frequency is the derivative of the phase your result is as expected.

$m(t) = cos(2\pi f(t) t)$

$\phi = 2\pi f(t) t$

$f(t) = Kt$ for a linear frequency ramp

thus phase versus time changes at the rate of $t^2$

$\phi = 2\pi Kt^2$

and the derivative of the phase (which is the instantaneous radian frequency) is:

$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = 4\pi Kt$

(Divide this by $2\pi$ to get instaneous frequency, but the source of the 2x discrepancy should now be very clear).

See the answer to this DSP Challenge that I posted that further explains this:

[Simulation of a Frequency ramp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31578/simulation-of-a-frequency-ramp)

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong.  Your signal is $$\sin(2\pi(2+10t)t)$$ which makes the instantaneous frequency $$(2\pi)^{-1}\frac{\rm d }{{\rm d}t}(2\pi(2+10t)t) = 2+20t$$.  Basically your "change of frequency" additionally increases the already currently accumulated phase, resulting in double the frequency change you were planning for.

Very common error when creating chirps.