# Chirp after T seconds

Tags: linear-chirp

Suppose we have this signal from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp)

$a(t)=\sin(\varphi_o + f_0t + (f_1-f_0)t^2/T)$

The article tells that T is a period of chirp modulation in which frequency changes. So my question is how to create signal with constant $f_1$ frequency after T?
[image: This is a wave from article]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to create signal with constant $f_1$ frequency after T?

Find the instantaneous phase at the end of the $T$ interval and keep adding it to the phase that makes the $\sin()$ "go round".

A plain simple oscillator at some frequency $f$ has its phase increasing at a constant rate.

Here is an example (in [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) but easily transferable to other platforms as well):

```
Fs = 44100; % Sampling frequency in Hz
T = 1; % Total duration of the signal in seconds
f = 120; % Frequency of the oscillator
t = 0:(1./Fs):(T - (1./Fs)); % Time vector
p = 2.0 .* pi .* t; %Phase vector
y = sin(f.*p);
```

Now `y` contains our 120 Hz sinusoid sampled at 44.1kHz.

Notice here that phase (`p`) is a "straight line" that grows at a **constant** rate of $\frac{2 \pi f}{Fs}$.

When the oscillator is "chirping", the rate of change of the phase is **variable**. For example:

```
Fs = 44100; % Sampling frequency in Hz
T = 1; % Total duration of the signal in seconds
f0 = 1; % Start chirp at
f1 = 120; % end chirp at (Better keep f1>f0)
t = 0:(1./Fs):(T - (1./Fs)); % Time vector
p = 2.0 .* pi .* t; %Phase vector
y = sin(f0.*p + 2.*pi.*(((f1-f0)/(2.*T)).*t.^2));
```

Now, this looks like:

[image]

And the **rate of change** of the phase of the $\sin$ is:

[image]

Now, from the first example, the phase "step" is `f.*p(2)-f.*p(1) == 0.017097` and from the second example, after doing:

```
s = diff(f0.*p + 2.*pi.*(((f1-f0)/(2.*T)).*t.^2)); % Get the first derivative of phase to find the **rate of change**.
```

The "last" rate of change is `s(end) == 0.017097`.

So, to have the oscillator stay at the chirp's concluding frequency, keep accumulating the phase at the constant rate you are after *from the last known value of the chirp's phase* (to avoid phase jumps). For example:

```
r = f0.*p + 2.*pi.*(((f1-f0)/(2.*T)).*t.^2);  % The phase as above.   
z = r(end) + cumsum(ones(1,T.*Fs).*0.017097); % A running sum of duration T.*Fs (samples).
```

Now, if you feed the combined result of `r, z` into the oscillator `y` with something like `y = sin([r,z]);` it would look like:

[image]

...with a **rate of change** of:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!
I thought about that I need to fix the phase of the signal.

Comment: @lisichkaggg No worries, all the best with your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the frequency to linearly increase from $f_0$ to $f_1$ (i.e., a chirp) then the solution is given in the answer to [this related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/31578/4298).

If you want a sinusoid with a constant frequency $f_0$ for $t<T$, and with frequency $f_1$ for $t>T$, then - since the phase is ($2\pi$ times) the integral of the frequency - the corresponding phase is given by

$$\frac{\phi(t)}{2\pi}=\begin{cases}f_0t,&t<T\\f_1(t-T)+f_0T,&t>T\end{cases}$$

where I've chosen the constants in such a way that the phase is continuous at $t=T$.

The desired signal is given by

$$x(t)=\sin(\phi(t))\tag{1}$$

Comment: The seconds answer is what I need.
Thanks for answer!