# Why does this transfer function estimation not work? System identification

Tags: frequency, transfer-function, frequency-response, frequency-domain, system-identification

**Goal:**

I have an unknow dynmical system $G(s)$ and I want to find it from measurement data, output $y(t)$ and input $u(t)$. The data is frequency responses.

**Method:**

I begun first with creating the data.

$$u(t) = A sin(2\pi \omega (t) t) $$

Where $\omega(t)$ is frequency in Hz over time and $A$ is fixed amplitude.
Let's say that we know our model, just to make our data inside the computer.

```
t = linspace(0.0, 50, 2800);
w = linspace(0, 100, 2800);
u = 10*sin(2*pi*w.*t); 
G = tf([3], [1 5 30]);
y = lsim(G, u, t);
```

Now when we have our data $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ and also $\omega(t)$. We can use Fast Fourier Transform to estimate the model.

First we find the complex ratio between $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ in frequency domain.

$$G(z) = \frac{FFT(y(t))}{FFT(u(t))}$$

```
  % Get the size of u or y or w
  r = size(u, 1);
  m = size(y, 1);
  n = size(w, 2);
  l = n/2;

  % Do Fast Fourier Transform for every input signal
  G = zeros(m, l*m); % Multivariable transfer function of magnitudes
  for i = 1:m
    % Do FFT
    fy = fft(y(i, 1:n));
    fu = fft(u(i, 1:n));

    % Create the complex ratios between u and y and cut it to half
    G(i, i:m:l*m) = (fy./fu)(1:l); % This makes so G(m,m) looks like an long idenity matrix
  end

  % Cut the frequency into half too and multiply it with 4
  w_half = w(1:l)*4;
```

Wee need to divide it into half due to frequencies have mirrors.

Now when we got our complex ratios. We need to create a discrete transfer function on this form:

$$G(z^{-1}) = \frac{B(z^{-1})}{A(z^{-1})}$$

$$A(z^{-1}) = 1 + A_1 z^{-1} + A_2 z^{-2} + A_3 z^{-3} + \dots + A_p z^{-p}$$
$$B(z^{-1}) = B_0 + B_1 z^{-1} + B_2 z^{-2} + B_3 z^{-3} + \dots + B_p z^{-p}$$

Where $p$ is the model order.

Now we are going to solve this as least squares.

$$A(z^{-1})G(z^{-1}) = B(z^{-1})$$

$$G(z^{-1}) = -A_1G(z^{-1})z^{-1} - \dots -A_pG(z^{-1})z^{-p} + B_0 + B_1 z^{-1} + \dots + B_p z^{-p}$$

Like this:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
G(z_1^{-1})z_1^{-1} & \dots & G(z_1^{-1})z_1^{-p} & 1 & z_1^{-1} & \dots & z_1^{-p} \\ 
G(z_2^{-1})z_2^{-1} & \dots & G(z_2^{-1})z_2^{-p} & 1 & z_2^{-1} & \dots & z_2^{-p} \\ 
G(z_3^{-1})z_3^{-1} & \dots & G(z_3^{-1})z_3^{-p} & 1 & z_3^{-1} & \dots & z_3^{-p} \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots   &  \vdots \\ 
G(z_l^{-1})z_l^{-1} & \dots & G(z_l^{-1})z_l^{-p} & 1 & z_l^{-1} & \dots & z_l^{-p} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
-A_1\\ 
\vdots \\
-A_p\\ 
B_0\\ 
B_1\\ 
\vdots \\
B_p
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
= \begin{bmatrix}
G(z_1^{-1})\\ 
G(z_2^{-1})\\ 
G(z_3^{-1})\\ 
\vdots \\ 
G(z_l^{-1})
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $z_i = e^{j\omega_i T}$ where $T$ is the sample ratio of measurement.

Let's call this equation above for $Ax=B$

MATLAB / Octave code for that:

```
  Gz = repmat(G', 1, p);
  Ir = repmat(eye(r), l, 1); % Just a I column for size r and length l
  Irz = repmat(eye(r), l, p);
  for n = 1:l
    for j = 1:p 
      z = (exp(1i*w_half(n)*sampleTime)).^(-j); % Do z = (e^(j*w*T))^(-p)
      sn = (n-1)*m + 1; % Start index for row
      tn = (n-1)*m + m; % Stop index for row
      sj = (j-1)*m + 1; % Start index for columns
      tj = (j-1)*m + m; % Stop index for columns
      Gz(sn:tn, sj:tj) = Gz(sn:tn, sj:tj)*z;    % G'(z^(-1))*z^(-1) 
      Irz(sn:tn, sj:tj) = Irz(sn:tn, sj:tj)*z;  % Ir*z^(-1) 
    end
  end
  % Join them all
  A = [Gz Ir Irz];
```

Now I going to solve this equation. We need to take accound that there are only complex values here. So we will solve this as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
real(A)\\ 
imag(A)
\end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix}
real(B)\\ 
imag(B)
\end{bmatrix}$$

```
  Ar = real(A);
  Ai = imag(A);
  Gr = real(G');
  Gi = imag(G');
  A = [Ar; Ai];
  B = [Gr; Gi];
  x = (inv(A'*A)*A'*B)'; % Ordinary least squares
```

And the numerator and denominator from $x$ is

```
  den = [1 (x(1, 1:p))] % -A_1, -A_2, -A_3, ... , -A_p
  num = (x(1, (p+1):end)) % B_0, B_1, B_2, ... , B_p
```

And here is the problem.

The variable $den$ have poles that are larger than 1 in unit circle. That' means that the model is unstable.

**Question:**

What have I missed?
What need to be done?

I assume that the least squares was not made correct. Right?

**What I have checked:**

I have checked that this code is correct:

```
  % Get the size of u or y or w
  r = size(u, 1);
  m = size(y, 1);
  n = size(w, 2);
  l = n/2;

  % Do Fast Fourier Transform for every input signal
  G = zeros(m, l*m); % Multivariable transfer function of magnitudes
  for i = 1:m
    % Do FFT
    fy = fft(y(i, 1:n));
    fu = fft(u(i, 1:n));

    % Create the complex ratios between u and y and cut it to half
    G(i, i:m:l*m) = (fy./fu)(1:l); % This makes so G(m,m) looks like an long idenity matrix
  end
```

Because I can plot the bode diagram of the measurement data

```
  % Cut the frequency into half too and multiply it with 4
  w_half = w(1:l)*4;

  % Plot the bode diagram of measurement data - This is not necessary for identification
  if(w_half(1) <= 0)
    w_half(1) = w_half(2); % Prevent zeros on the first index. In case if you used w = linspace(0,...
  end
  semilogx(w_half, 20*log10(abs(G))); % This have the same magnitude and frequencies as a bode plot
```

Assume that our model is

$$G(s) = \frac{3}{s^2 + 5s + 30}$$

There fore our bode diagram from data is going to look like this. The left picture shows the data-bode diagram and the right picture shows the bode diagram from the transfer function model.

[image]

You can follow the math logic at equation 14 here:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920023413.pdf

Comment: You optimization constraint, does not take into account causality and stability as I see, so you are bound to see results which have poles outside unit circle. Isn't it? It's a plain unconstrained least sqaures problem

Comment: @Dspguysam Yes. It's uncosntrained. As the report says.

Comment: Added my thoughts in the answer

Comment: @Dspguysam Hi! One curious question. Should I take the power of negative such as `z = (e^(j*w*T))^(-p)` or can I remove the negative sign? `z = (e^(j*w*T))^p = e^(j*w*p*T)` ? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I see, it's a simple line curve fitting, you would need to cosntraint poles to be inside unit circle( this can be turned into a convex constraint), the objective of least sqaures is an $l_2$ norm minimization (which is also convex), so you would need to setup a convex optimization problem to ensure stability and poles inside unit circle.

One easier approach would be the following:

formulating the convex problem might be not so trivial, especially if not with optimization background, so I suggest that you

> go ahead with this unconstrained problem, if you get a pole outside
>   unit circle in the z plane, keep the pole at same frequency and scale
>   magnitude of pole to lie just within unit circle, that should give you
>   a very decent approximation of the frequency response.

Aside in general:

Since you mention that the system function is related to input and output as the following, pretty much describing an LTI system as
$$G(z) = \frac{FFT(y(t))}{FFT(u(t))}$$

Then I would suggest the following, instead of taking a sinusoid as input, take white gaussian noise, suppose $u(t)$ is gaussian proceed that is IID for different time instances, then it's Fourier transform is simply $\frac{N_o}{2}$ for all frequencies. That means the Fourier transform if output $y(t)$ is simply $\frac{N_o}{2}G(f)$, so simply taking the FFT of the output of the system when white gaussian noise is passed through it, directly providers the system transfer function.

I think this is a much starightforward and easy approach. Can be easily simulates in MATLAB. Make sure to run Monte Carlo simulation over noise

Comment: Can you show me? I must be a frequency response :) Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are looking for MATAB code?, Plot?

Comment: There is no problem with FFT here. I have showed that.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for MATLAB code. Not plot. I know that my $G(z)$ are correct. It's more how I solve this system. Is this correct $z_i^{-p} = (e^{j\omega_i T})^{-p}$ ?

Comment: Ok, so you would want a MATLAB code to find system function using the method I explained? If yes, I can provide that

Comment: Well, I want a function that can estimate a TF from frequency response. But sure, let me have a look how you are doing :)

Comment: my goal is to solve equation 14 here. It's for MIMO TF. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920023413.pdf

Comment: :) then let us try and solve your query, because my simulation wouldn't help you solve the particular problem. so are you looking to estimate TF both the phase and magnitude response? Or just magnitude reaponse

Comment: Magnitude only and frequency. Look at the equation 14 it that report. It's for MIMO TF, but SISO have the same math.

Comment: No need to optimize here. Just follow the report. NASA created it .

Comment: FIY, system identification can be much more accurate with sine wave stimulus than with white noise stimulus. Especially if you're interested in modeling high-frequency dynamics

Comment: I agree that gaussian noise might be a better option, but it is incorrect that its fft has the same value at each frequency. The expected value of the magnitude would satisfy that value, but the phase would be all over the place. A better approach would be Welch's method, which is also used in the Matlab/Octave function tfestimate.

Comment: The least sqaures is itslef an optimization, sorry can't read the full report, but I looked at the section you pointed, it doesn't talk about location of poles, it's just talking about the best fit, in the least sqaures sense, the objective itslef is allowing poles to lie anywhere else, do they do some trick later on to reject any pole lying outside the unit circle

Comment: By the way! Assume that we have a MIMO TF. Can we convert it to MIMO state space model then?

Comment: Because I know how to use Recursive Least Squares to estimate a TF from random data e.g. frequency response. But that is only for SISO.

Comment: If I have two SISO TF models. Then I can find the $A_p$ and $B_p$ ? They are matrices in the report. Look at equation 11 and 10

Comment: You like system identification? :)

Comment: @fibonatic, that's why I mention to a average out using Monte Carlo simulation, also pwelch will only help us get the magnitude of Fourier transform, not phase

Comment: Can you show us a pratical example with an arbitary TF? :)

Comment: @ben can you please explain why it is easier with sinusoid, it is pretty straightforward with white noise, (I can always average out over certain Monte Carlo runs to get very close to the expected value of the noise power, which is very much constant) using sinuoids we would get addition two shifted copies of the system function, which is not easy to extract as the white noise case.

Comment: @daniel I understand that it is written by NASA, but if the problem is not cosntarined the least sqaures finds the best fit, it doesn't care about where the poles ly for that, maybe later on they provide a method to curb away these poles and make the system stable. But it's very obvious that if you do not constraint the space, the solution can ly anywhere depending on objective

Comment: With an ideal ADC, you'd get the same result that's for sure. Picture this case,

Say that at 2 kHz you already have  80 dB of attenuation, the response at 2 kHz will likely be buried in noise. Synchronous demodulaiton allows you to extract the amplitude and phase. 

It's useful to identify high-frequency resonances and anti-resonances.

The caveat is that you need more data and it takes longer.

Comment: @Dspguysam So you mean that I must have constrained opimization in this case?

Comment: @daniel...here is my suggestion...formulating the convex problem might be not so trivial, especially if not with optimization background, so I suggest that you go ahead with this unconstrained problem, if you get a pole outside unit circle in the z plane, keep the pole at same frequency and scale magnitude of pole to lie just within unit circle, that should give you a very decent approximation of the frequency response.

Comment: @Dspguysam Sounds dificullt. I think I will solve this with Recursive Least Squares :) Do you like system identification? I have a library that you might like

Comment: @daniel, sure, please share the link, by the way, it's not that difficult, you already have the setup in place, after least sqaures suppose you get a pole at $2e^{(j\frac{\pi}{3})}$ simply scale the amplitude to 0.95 from 2, you would very much aproach the given frqeuency response.

Comment: @Dspguysam I will try to find the $A_p$ and $B_p$ from RLS. Here. If you want, you can contribute to OCID. Observer Controller Identification. Very excellent algorithm. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/mataveid

Comment: @Dspguysam Also look at this report. It follows the same as OKID report. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2320/a28c5583fdd37365799b3c9b30cafbdc0b90.pdf

Comment: @Dspguysam Just follow equation 16 to 22 and then you have the OCID algorithm. You can borrow code from okid.m file in my library.

Comment: @Dspguysam Need some work too on ERA/DC algorithm

Comment: @Dspguysam See my approach using a properly swept sine wave including the code. I didn't compare with white noise and least squares (Wiener-Hopf method)  but if you are doing that in this one it will be very interesting to see how the approaches compare. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66541/how-can-i-plot-the-frequency-response-on-a-bode-diagram-with-fast-fourier-transf

Comment: @Dan thanks for sharing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106913/discussion-on-answer-by-dsp-guy-sam-why-does-this-transfer-function-estimation-n).