# Frequency response of discrete PT1 in MATLAB

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-response

I want to calculate the frequency response of a discrete PT1 system with T=T1 and K=1. (the code is at the bottom of the question)
To validate the magnitude response, I want to use an sinusoidal input signal with linearly increasing frequency from 0 to fs/2.
The magnitude response should be the envelope of the transient response.
However, this is only the case if I change the line

`u = sin(2*pi*f.*t);`

to

`u = sin(pi*f.*t);`

Why? I assume that I have any kind of faulty reasoning here, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Full code:

```
clear

%% Input (linear frequency sweep)
Ts = .1e-3;
duration = 30;
t = (0:Ts:duration);
fs = 1/Ts;
f = (fs/2)*t/duration;
u = sin(2*pi*f.*t); 

%% PT1-system continuous
T1 = 1e-3;
G = tf(1,[T1 1]);

%% PT1 discretized
H = c2d(G,Ts,'zoh');

%% PT1 trasient response
x0 = 0;
x = lsim(H,u,[],x0,'zoh');

%% PT1 freq. response
[h,~] = freqz(H.Numerator{1:end},H.Denominator{1:end},f,fs);

%% Plot
figure(1),clf(1),hold on
plot(u),plot(x),plot(abs(h))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error by myself now.

I did not use the instantaneous frequency for the calculation of the sweep signal, as stated [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31578/simulation-of-a-frequency-ramp) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency#Instantaneous_frequency).

The corrected code is:

```
clear

%% Input (linear frequency sweep)
Ts = .1e-3;
duration = 30;
t = (0:Ts:duration);
fs = 1/Ts;
f = (fs/2)*t/duration;
finst = 1/2*(fs/2)/duration*t;
u = sin(2*pi*finst.*t);

%% PT1-system continuous
T1 = 1e-3;
G = tf(1,[T1 1]);

%% PT1 discretized
H = c2d(G,Ts,'zoh');
x0 = 0;

%% PT1 trasient response
x = lsim(H,u,[],x0,'zoh');

%% PT1 freq. response
[h,~] = freqz(H.Numerator{1:end},H.Denominator{1:end},f,fs);

%% Plot
figure(1),clf(1),hold on
plot(u),plot(x),plot(abs(h))
```